# Is there anyway to add background images when using code pen?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to set an image as the background but because it's a browser bases editor, I cannot just link the photo as they are not saved together.

```
       <body>
        <div id="backG"> <img src="(image link. i didnt add the link here as it is very long) " alt="concert stadium"> 
     </div>
     <div id="mainPage">

  <div id="navBar">
     <div id="Logo">
        <h1 style="font-weight:bold;"> Ice Arena  
        </h1>
     </div>
     <ul>
        <li style="color:#ffe700;">
           Home
        </li>
        <li>
           Gallery
        </li>
        <li>
           Order Form
        </li>
        <li>
           The Arena
        </li>
        <li>
           Contact Us
           </li>
     <    /ul>
      </div>


   </div>

 </body>#
```

here is the CSS for the photo.

```
   #backG{
  diplay:block;
  border:0;

    }
```

Comment: The code is pretty useless without the image URL. That's the only relevant piece of information.

Comment: oh ok sorry, here it is "https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwim1tniv_7TAhWI7BQKHQI4DGMQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fxoio.de%2Fen%2Fstadium-visualization-gmp-tokyo%2F&psig=AFQjCNHQuOOarnhHXCDCks-Rn12JT_CPZA&ust=1495370608109541"

Comment: Have you tried to open that link directly in a browser? It's not an image at all.

Comment: damn. im sorry. i just copies the link address from google images instead of copying the image address. my bad

Answer (score 0):

Free Codepen does not let you host your own images, so you have to upload them somewhere else and link to them. A lot of people use [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [imgur](http://imgur.com/)
for this. Hope this helps!

Comment: i have tried doing this but it hasnt worked. i dont know what i did wrong. ill ad the code to the original post

Comment: Does my codepen example fit what you're trying to achieve? https://codepen.io/alessi42/pen/dWQpGQ

Comment: kind of yes. but for some reason when i use the same code but with my image, whether it is the original image, or from imgur. it doesn't work and just comes up with the alt text

Comment: Can you provide a link to the image? Either original or from imgur